# Can't import package file (no module named...) (Python)

Tags: python, module, package

I am receving this error while I am try to run the code (from CMD):

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numbers.hog'; numbers is not a package
```

[image]

Here is the `hog.py` file code...

```
from skimage import feature

class HOG:
    def __init__(self, orientations = 9, pixelsPerCell = (8, 8),
        cellsPerBlock = (3, 3), normalize = False):
        self.orienations = orientations
        self.pixelsPerCell = pixelsPerCell
        self.cellsPerBlock = cellsPerBlock
        self.normalize = normalize

def describe(self, image):
    hist = feature.hog(image,
    orientations = self.orienations,
    pixels_per_cell = self.pixelsPerCell,
    cells_per_block = self.cellsPerBlock,
    normalize = self.normalize)

    return hist
```

...and the main (`train.py`) which return the error.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from numbers.hog import HOG
from numbers import dataset
import argparse
import pickle as cPickle


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required = True,
    help = "path to the dataset file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required = True,
    help = "path to where the model will be stored")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


(digits, target) = dataset.load_digits(args["dataset"])
data = []

hog = HOG(orientations = 18, pixelsPerCell = (10, 10),
    cellsPerBlock = (1, 1), normalize = True)

for image in digits:
    image = dataset.deskew(image, 20)
    image = dataset.center_extent(image, (20, 20))

    hist = hog.describe(image)
    data.append(hist)

model = LinearSVC(random_state = 42)
model.fit(data, target)

f = open(args["model"], "w")
f.write(cPickle.dumps(model))
f.close()
```

I don't uderstand why it gives me error on module package. `numbers` is a package, why it don't import it as well (as it seems) ?

[image]

UPDATE: tried to put `from .hog import HOG` and then execute from CMD..It prints:

```
No module named '__main__.hog'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Is it crazy ? `hog.py` is in the main package together with the other files. As you can see, it also contains HOG class.... Can't understand.. Some one can reproduce the error ?

In the IDE console it prints:

```
usage: train.py [-h] -d DATASET -m MODEL
train.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--dataset, -m/--model
```

This should be correct as soon as it is executed in IDE because the program MUST run in CMD.

UPDATE 2: for who is interested, this is the project https://github.com/VAUTPL/Number_Detection

Comment: Did you try replacing this line "from numbers.hog import HOG" with "from hog import HOG"? Both files are in the same directory after all.

Comment: It gives me error (red line) writing like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `from numbers.hog import HOG` to `from hog import HOG` and 
change `from numbers import dataset` to `import dataset`.

You are already in the "numbers" package so you don't have to precise it again when you import it. 
When you type `from numbers import dataset`, Python will look for a package `numbers` (inside the actual package) that contains a `dataset.py` file.

If your `train.py` was outside the `numbers` package then you have to put the package name (`numbers`) before.

Answer (score 0):

**Important**
numbers is a python standard package
https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html

Check if you are not really importing that package or **rename** your package to a more specific name.

Also:

It might looks like python doesnt recognize your package.

Open a python shell and write:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Check if your number path is there.

If it's not there you have to add it.

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```

Comment: Gives me back 'Cannot import name hog'.. but it accept it as a modification of the original "from numbers.hog import HOG"

Comment: mm python doesnt recognize your package, I update my answer

Comment: I updated my answer. Check if you are not importing python standar number package and rename/add your package to python path

Comment: It print the various Python paths and also the "DetectNumbers\numbers" folder/package. I mean, I've already added this project path to the variables main path (of Python..)
It's so strange...

Comment: I think python is trying to import official number package https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html. Please rename your package to something else

Comment: Still error, even after I changed package name and updated path.. Error is "from numdetect import hog" No module named numdetect

Comment: first run "import numdetect" then "from numdetect import hog"

Comment: Nothing, same error....But, if I run code in IDE it seems to work...Traceback is "usage: train.py [-h] -d DATASET -m MODEL
train.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--dataset, -m/--model" which redirect to CMD...and from CMD it don't work :(

Comment: but that's another issue, it not an import error anymore. It says you need to pass -d and -m

Comment: I think now it's importing number modules fine, you need to pass a path to dataset file and a path to store the model as parameters

Answer (score 0):

Your train.py file is already in the package "numbers", so you don't have to import numbers.

Try this instead:

```
from hog import HOG
```

I saw  in comment that it gives you "error (red line)".
Can you be more precise, because I don't see errors there.

Comment: Excuse me, I am not English and I don't understand "stressed with red lines" and which error ?

Comment: https://s2.postimg.org/ct1fgbund/stressed.jpg ----  it's also possible I am saying it wrong... Ok, underlining..

Comment: Just write from hog import HOG, do not import anything else said in other answers or comments (just to see). Can you run your program even if the code is stressed with red lines ? If yes try to do it.

Comment: Gives error ---> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numdetect' in CMD, in IDE is `usage: train.py [-h] -d DATASET -m MODEL
train.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--dataset, -m/--model`

Comment: I don't know what your IDE so I can't help you there. Delete the line  "import numdetect" in your code please.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm, but it's not important...Already tried without "import numdetect" but with no success...
You are running the code for yourself ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150600/discussion-between-zcode-and-link).